# How to resolve Signature Verification Results false positives?

Tags: windows, security, certificate, dll, digital-signature

I noticed that there are six DLLs in ***C:\Windows\System32*** that **sigverif.exe** flags as not having been digitally signed - even though they have been. After digging into it a bit, it looks like the certificate used to sign those DLLs is expired. I'm guessing that's the reason for the false positive, but would like confirmation.  If possible, how can I resolve it?

Windows 11 Pro 21H2 22000.739

msvcp110.dll, msvcp120.dll, msvcr110.dll, msvcr120.dll, vccorlib110.dll and vccorlib120.dll

[Signature Verification Results - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LE2w.png)

Comment: It is *not* a false positive if the certificate used to sign those dlls has expired.

Comment: If it is not a problem, why do you want to resolve it? Maybe install the latest version of the Visual Studio Runtime files.

Comment: I started using a cool app, Total Registry, but in order to run as Administrator, it requires the use of an unsigned driver.  I have Secure Boot enabled, so was researching how I could accomplish this and came across sigverif.exe.  I ran it, expecting there to not be any unsigned drivers, and was surprised to see some.  I'm just trying to educate myself.  That being said, I have the latest version of the VS runtime files.  Sounds like there's nothing that can be done.  Is that accurate?